# Using external libraries in Xamarin Android.

Tags: android, xamarin

Is there a way we can use external libraries in our Xamarin Android project? 
For Ex. If we want better animations & transitions, I see that there are libraries like these available for Android 
https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidViewAnimations

How do we use them in Xamarin? Any help is appreciated. 
Thanks 
Supreet

Comment: Could this be the solution http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/java_integration_overview/binding_a_java_library_(.jar)/

Comment: Thank you for that really useful answer Selvin You made my life

Comment: we are not targeting multiplatform & we don't do Android in Java because we don't know java :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access native Android/Java libraries from Xamarin.Android, you need to create a binding for them.  Xamarin has [docs and samples](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/java_integration_overview/binding_a_java_library_%28.jar%29/) of how to create a binding library.

Comment: yes Jason, I found the URL after posting the question. I am going through it now. Thanks